# Run exe with custom arguments using powershell

Tags: powershell

I need to run(install) an exe which takes some custom parameter (arguments)

```
install.exe --no-prompt -u username -p password
```

The above command is provided by the 3rd party team to allow silent installation of the agent

Since I am trying to install this via powershell, I want to know how to pass the custom parameters.

Note: This exe is a 3rd party component. I can run command to install an exe with credentials object. But the same is not working in this case.

Comment: Need clarification of what precisely you mean by "I want to know how to pass the custom parameters".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Executables can be run in PowerShell. Try:

```
& install.exe --no-prompt -u username -p password
```

It might require giving a full path to the executable.

```
& C:\Users\me\Downloads\newapp\install.exe --no-prompt -u username -p password
```

If this does not do it, be sure to copy and paste any messages into the question.

Comment: The `&` (invocation) operator isn't strictly necessary if the command to run doesn't contain one or more spaces.

Answer (score 1):

```
Start-Process -FilePath C:\run.exe -ArgumentList "--no-prompt -u username -p password"
```